# What to do about a new user repeatedly posting poor questions?

Tags: discussion, new-users

In the last few days I've noticed a new user has posted ~5 questions; most are of poor quality, showing little to no research. Some of the questions have been flagged as too broad or unclear, but not all. This user is a new DM, and it seems that the user is trying to have his campaign written by forum but is spreading it across multiple posts.

Do we have a policy on how to handle this, or should we simply downvote each question until the user learns how to use the site correctly?

Comment: In this particular particular case (if I'm thinking of the same posts over the last two days) on one of the posts I did drop an invite to [chat] and later saw the user there. So that may also be a route to (a) help them with their homebrew and (b) provide "softer" course-correction on mainsite usage.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Treat each post on its own merit; if you see a pattern of behavior go ahead and send up a custom flag.

Posts should be voted/commented upon regardless of author. We're all human, of course, but to the extent that we're aware that we may harbor a bias against an author (borne of experience), we should double-check ourselves that we're voting the post, not the user.

That said, there are times that a user is doing... ~things~, none of which seem, individually, to merit action but which, when taken as a whole, bother you. In that case go ahead and raise a flag for moderator attention, please. One of our charges is to keep an eye out for "consistent, low-quality contributions over time."

We have some tools to help with that, we raise flags ourselves just to keep our eye on someone, but it's a tough job, it's a subjective job, and it requires sustained effort. Luckily, that's exactly the sort of problem that an educated and well-intentioned crowd can help a lot with.

The "in need of moderator intervention (be specific)" flag reason is great for this: raise a flag on any post by the author and explain the *pattern* you're seeing. You probably won't see any response from us<sup>*</sup>, but please know that we appreciate the help!

<sup>* - If we end up taking no action it's strange and hard to go back and find the initial flagger to explain; if we do take mod action it's not really appropriate to do so.</sup>

Comment: [Related meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8331/23970) on dealing with an account suspected of being a group. TL;DR: I give basically the same answer there.

Comment: Am I incorrect in that after so many "bad" posts (I wouldn't have a clue how many it takes) in a row, or in a certain amount of time, or something to that effect, a users account is automatically, temporarily suspended? Or is that a mod action? I vaguely remember that I may have read it somewhere or that it has happened before, though I don't know whether it was automatic or if a mod did it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @PurpleMonkey yes, there's an "automatic question ban" when many of their questions are negatively scored, closed, or deleted.

Comment: Andrew's correct: it's automatic and mods can neither impose/lift such a ban nor do we even know the exact criteria for it (like you-all).

Answer (score 3):

The site code will take care of this automatically, if the user does not improve.  The exact mechanisms are secret, but if a user gets enough Bad Post Points of a type then the site won't let them post any more stuff of that type until the score goes up from editing or like a month passes so deletion Bad Points go away or something like that.

Helping them before then is obviously better, though.